# CNN-LSTM structure: post vs pre padding?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, padding, conv-neural-network

In a structure like: CNN -> LSTM -> Dense
The input is variable length (ex Speech Recognition CTC), and need to be padded.
Will the choice between pre and post padding affect the performance?
I read [Effects of padding on LSTMs and CNNs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07288.pdf)
Is it true that pre vs post will not affect the performance as long as the input layer is CNN?

Answer (score 0):

As the paper shows

[image: find source in initial question]

So if you apply post padding to the LSTM, you will clearly have a worse performance.

Since LSTMs learn based on a sequence of data and try to find relations to the past, adding white noise,i.e. LSTM pre-padding, in the input will prevent them from building this relation.

If the pre-padding is added to the CNN, I believe that the performance of the LSTM will remain unaffected, as the output of the CNN doesn't change.

From my understanding CNN post padding and LSTM pre padding is the same thing, and may result in worse perfromance.

Generally speaking, you can get solid information by reading papers. In forums you will read about other people's opinions.